AppDynamics - AD Agent init ERROR Cannot access RandomAccessFile java.io.IOException: Could not create directory
Error while appdynamics agent.
[AD Agent init] Wed Aug 07 13:52:33 GMT 2024[INFO]: JavaAgent - Using Java Agent Version [Server Agent #22.4.0.33722 v22.4.0 GA compatible with 4.4.1.0 rb331a334461edd5eb1d77f0c99bec1f876202683 release/22.4.0]
[AD Agent init] Wed Aug 07 13:52:33 GMT 2024[INFO]: JavaAgent - Running IBM Java Agent [No]
[AD Agent init] Wed Aug 07 13:52:33 GMT 2024[INFO]: JavaAgent - Java Agent Directory [/opt/app-agent/ver22.4.0.33722]
[AD Agent init] Wed Aug 07 13:52:33 GMT 2024[INFO]: JavaAgent - Java Agent AppAgent directory [/opt/app-agent/ver22.4.0.33722]
Agent logging directory set to [/opt/app-agent/ver22.4.0.33722/logs]
[AD Agent init] Wed Aug 07 13:52:33 GMT 2024[INFO]: JavaAgent - Agent logging directory set to [/opt/app-agent/ver22.4.0.33722/logs]
2024-08-07 13:52:33,529 AD Agent init ERROR Cannot access RandomAccessFile java.io.IOException: Could not create directory /opt/app-agent/ver22.4.0.33722/logs/unknown java.io.IOException: Could not create directory /opt/app-agent/ver22.4.0.33722/logs/unknown

How to fix this issue.
